# Python: OAuth Library for Linux and Windows

Tags: python, oauth

Is there a python library for oAuth which can be run on Window and Linux?

On window I am using `python-oauth` but I could not find an installation for Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Python libraries that don't rely on native code or platform-specific APIs are portable. I don't see any of that in `python-oauth` or `python-oauth2`.

So your current library should work fine on Linux.

Comment: is there any installation instructions or just to copy the oauth.py to  ..\Lib\site-packages?

Comment: Run `python setup.py install`. Or, if your package is in the Python Package Index, run `easy_install your-package-name` or `pip install your-package-name` (you might have to do this as superuser).

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth) as well. Both `python-oauth` and `python-oauth2` are fairly dated at this point and are going to give you trouble with OAuth 2.0.